# This issue comes when i upgrade android studio from 3.1.4 to 3.2.0

Tags: android, android-studio

It’s I have delete build folder and also deleted ids.xml but the issue is not resolving. I have implemented ffmeg.

```
Android resource compilation failed Output:  C:\Users\hp\Desktop\New folder\SocialMediaRepository\8-Nov SocialMediaApp\SocialMediaApp\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:3331: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
```

Comment: Please paste your values.xml.

Comment: Looks like you have syntax problem with your values.xml

Comment: values.xml is auto-generated. and after generating there is a item like 
<item name="touchId" type="id">2564</item> this but it must be <item name="touchId" type="id"></item>

I have searched for this issue and some suggests to delete ids.xml file and some suggests to delete build folder. I have tried both but still stuck in this issue

Comment: Can you paste your ids.xml file? Because if you are removing the value it should work as I did the same and it worked.

Comment: This is my ids.xml

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <item name="touchId" type="id"/>

</resources>`

Comment: Technically it should work. Check for the third party libraries if they have wrong declaration inside their values folder.

Comment: My ids.xml is not linking to auto-generate values.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by updating

```
<item> name="touchId" type="id"2645 </item> to <item name="touchId" type="id"/>
```

in the following directory

**C:\Users\hp.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\vidsta-1.0.0.aar\db27c0f2f79c23c8406b39688f41e54e\res\values**